# Center two lis inside ul horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have two lis inside a ul. And I'm not able to make the lis center. 
I can center the li by giving fixed width to it. Can it be done without giving fixed width?

```css
.PhNumber_email_list {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.PhNumber_email_list li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.PhNumber_email_list li input {
  border: 2px solid #196edf;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  color: #3f3f3f;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<ul class="PhNumber_email_list">
  <li>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
    <p class="hint">Your email is kept private and secure</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" class="PhNumber_mask" placeholder="Phone Number  (Optional)">
    <p class="hint">Get exclusive support</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Heres the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3lackRos3/99stwpnp/1/)

Comment: So the problem is the `<p class="hint" />` underneath or what's not centered?

Comment: like so ? http://jsfiddle.net/99stwpnp/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/99stwpnp/3/

use `box-sizing:border-box` for `input` so that the `padding` is calculated from inside

and instead of `float:left` use `display:inline-block` so that you center it without giving `width`

```css
.PhNumber_email_list {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.PhNumber_email_list li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.PhNumber_email_list li input {
  border: 2px solid #196edf;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  color: #3f3f3f;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<ul class="PhNumber_email_list">
  <li>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
    <p class="hint">Your email is kept private and secure</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" class="PhNumber_mask" placeholder="Phone Number  (Optional)">
    <p class="hint">Get exclusive support</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If using a percentage for the width of the `<li>` is ok I think you can. In the following example I've added `box-sizing: border-box` to the `li` and the `li input` to include the padding and the border size in the width. I've added a `width: 50%` to the `li` and changed the `margin` into a `padding`.

```css
.PhNumber_email_list {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.PhNumber_email_list li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  width: 50%;
}
.PhNumber_email_list li input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #196edf;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  color: #3f3f3f;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<ul class="PhNumber_email_list">
  <li>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
    <p class="hint">Your email is kept private and secure</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" class="PhNumber_mask" placeholder="Phone Number  (Optional)">
    <p class="hint">Get exclusive support</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```